# How many distinct solutions for the equation

Tags: combinatorics

Given $K \in \mathbb{N}$ with $K \ge 3$, let $x, y, z\in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$ be such that $x + y + z = K$. How can I determine the number of cases where $x, y, z$ are distinct without using partitions?

My approach was to assign $x, y, z$ to new variables $p, q, r$
such that $p = x , q + 1= y , r + 2 = z$.
Now the equation becomes $p + (q+1) + (r+2) = K $, or $p + q + r = K-3$ .

My next step was to find the number of solutions of this equation and arrange them in ascending order, then converting them back to $x, y, z$, but I am not sure how to do so. Also I suspect there is a major flaw of overcounting when arranging the solutions in ascending order.

Comment: Given that you only have three variables, you can use Stars and Bars to count the unrestricted number, then subtract off the cases where two or more are equal (those can be counted by hand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let x + y + z = 9

1. s: all integral solutions of equation

,A:x=y
,B:x=z
,C:y=z

1. i = $$|A’  \cap B’\cap C’|$$

1.i = |s|-|A|-|B|-|C|+2k

2.k = $$|A  \cap B|$$

2.if 2x + y = 9, then x = 0,1,2,3,4

|A|= |B| =|C| = 5
,k = 1{x=3=y=z}

1.|s| = C(11,2)=55

1.i = 55-15+2=42

Comment: I see it now, thank you